# How can i color the richTextBox specific text once in yellow and once in red?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I have below code in the form to add a text to `RichTextBox`.

```
public void SetText(string text)
{
    richTextBox2.Text = text;
    SetRichTextBoxColors(true);
}

private void SetRichTextBoxColors(bool yellow)
{
    if (yellow)
    {
        // color text in red
    }
    else
    {
        // color text in yellow
    }
}
```

Each button click the `SetText` get a new text and add it to the `richTextbox2`.
I want that first time the added text will be in yellow then the next time it will be in red then yellow again then red...

In a new form I did:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _form1.SetText(textBox1.Text);
}
```

What should I put in `SetRichTextBoxColors` method to make it work?

Comment: Your requirement is not clear enough, What is the difficulty that you are facing now?

Comment: @un-lucky In the SetText how do i make that once it will be true and once false ?

Comment: So you want to Add the Text from Textbox To RichTextBox, If the Text from the TextBox and Text in the RichBox are same then the color will be red otherwise it will be yellow. Am i right?

Comment: To add a text to `RichTextBox` you should use `AppendText` you should not assign a new value to `Text` property. It removes all previous added texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a flag at form level to determine if you should use yellow color. Then in the method, checking the flag, decide to use which color, then add the colored text and inverse the flag:

```
bool yellow = true;
public void AddText(string text)
{
    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
    richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0; ;
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = yellow ? Color.Yellow : Color.Red;
    richTextBox1.SelectedText = text;
    yellow = !yellow;
}
```

**Note**

- To replace the whole contents, you can assign value to `Text` property.
- To append a text, you can use `AppendText` method.
- To use a single color for the whole contents, you can assign a color to `ForeColor` property.
- To insert a colored text at any index of `RichTextBox` you can set  `SelectionStart` to the specified index, `SelectionLength` to `0`, `SelectionColor` to specified color and then assign the given text to `SelectionText` property.

Comment: I think, `SelectionLength` should be `text.Length`

Comment: @דניאלרשת Just copy the method and paste it in your class and you will see it works properly :)

Comment: @un-lucky It make the richtextbox ignore current selection, to prevent changing color of current selection.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Working perfect :)